# Import data command missing tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, import

Oracle Import missing tables

I am using this command to import tables.

```
imp FILE=D:\swr\SWR_18_08_2019.dmp FROMUSER=SWR TOUSER=SWR
```

I expect the output of all tables need to import.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you modify the command to

```
imp swr file=D:\swr\SWR_18_08_2019.dmp log=swr_imp.log ignore=y
```

In other words:

- specify username which will own data you import (`swr`)
- include `log` file (to see what's going on)
- use `ignore` parameter which will skip `CREATE TABLE` statements if tables already exist and will load only data
- `fromuser`/`touser` seems to be unnecessary

Then run it and see what happens. If it still doesn't work, please, post an excerpt from the log file so that we'd see the result.

Comment: @littlefootSir, I have altered table space and then Imported again. Now one table showing importing which has 1 crore records. Will it import or not? If this table not imported, will next tables import?

Comment: If import says (for example) "12345 rows imported", then yes - all of them WERE imported. If one table fails to import (because of any error), tables that follow will be imported (except if there's an error for any of those tables), but - generally speaking, one table that fails will NOT prevent other tables to be imported. I suggest you to check log file.